# Why can't I find the DirectX template?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, directx

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows desktop, but I can't really find the DirectX template, FILE -> New project -> Visual C++ , but there's neither a DirectX template nor a Windows app folder-sector. I've searched this in Google but no one seem to have posted about it.  Where is the template?

Comment: Why are you expecting a DirectX project template?

Comment: It is not downloadable and tons of people own it , and it could be really useful for me

Comment: Sure you have [this version (at leastUpdate2)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/04/08/directx-graphics-development-with-visual-studio-2013-and-update-2.aspx) installed?

Comment: Not sure , but this link might be useful , thank you

Comment: **Desktop people write stuff from scratch.** No such DX templates! :) I think you're looking for App stuff so head over to VS 2013 Community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "DirectX" templates provided by Visual Studio are for Windows Store, Windows phone, or Universal apps. They are only provided in the VS 2013 Express for Windows, VS 2013 Pro+, or VS 2013 Community edition.

There are only **two** built-in Visual C++ Win32 desktop templates in Visual Studio:

- Win32 Console Application
- Win32 project

As others have noted, if you want to build for Windows Store, Windows phone, or Universal apps you need (a) Windows 8.1 and (b) some other edition of VS 2013.

If you are writing a Win32 desktop application and/or have Windows 7, consider downloading and installing this template: [Direct3D Win32 Game Visual Studio template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2015/01/06/direct3d-win32-game-visual-studio-template.aspx)

Also, I highly recommend using VS 2013 Community rather than VS 2013 Express for Windows Desktop if you fit the quite generous license requirements--if not, buy VS 2013 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the correct version of Visual Studio. The desktop version doesn't have DirectX for Windows store apps. You need to download [Visual Studio 2013 Express For Windows](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx), scroll down to `Express 2013 for Windows` or [direct link](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9832256)